# Creating summary statistic table from subsets of data in R

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
Time     Carbon       OD
 0       Sucrose      1.13
 0       Citric acid  1.54
24       Histidine    2.1
24       Glutamine    1.7
48       Maleic acid  2.1
48       Furm acid    3.1
72       Tryptophan   2.3
72       Serine       1.2
72       etc          etc
```

It has four time points, and 9 different carbons that can be split into three groups (organic acids, sugars, amino acids).

EDIT - if its helpful, the OD was measured for each carbon at each time point 8 times. Previously I used this code to create summary statistics for the entire thing:

```
summary <- aggregate(dataset2$OD,
                   by = list(Time = dataset2$Time, Carbon = dataset2$Carbon),
                   FUN = function(x) c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x),
                                       n = length(x)))
summary <- do.call(data.frame, dataset2)
summary$se <- dataset2$x.sd / sqrt(dataset2$x.n)
```

But now I would like to generate the same summary statistics for the means of each of the three groups, if possible, so I would get something like this:

```
Time    Group    OD    SD    n    SE
  0     Group 1    
 24     Group 1 
 48     Group 1
 72     Group 1
  0     Group 2
```

I'm not quite sure how to specify this in my code?

Comment: You said four time points and 9 carbons, but you only provided 1 time point per carbon and only 3 carbons. Can you provide the minimal dataset required for you produce the summary statistics?

Comment: sorry, I've done that now!

Comment: This is still not good enough, since you only have _one_ time point for each `Carbon`. You cannot calculate the SD and SE with only one data point.

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`:

```
dataset2 %>%
  group_by(Time, Group)
  summarise(OD = mean(OD),
            SD = sd(OD),
            n = n())
```

Comment: Might want to add the standard error to that `SE = SD/sqrt(n)`